# STM32F4 SPI issue

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, spi

I'am using STM32F407vg and i'am trying to write data in SPI data register, the following code shows the configuration function

```
void init_SPI1(void){

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_InitStruct;

// enable clock for used IO pins
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

/* configure pins used by SPI1
     * PA4 = NSS
 * PA5 = SCK
 * PA6 = MISO
 * PA7 = MOSI
 */
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_7 | GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_5|GPIO_Pin_4;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

// connect SPI1 pins to SPI alternate function
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource4, GPIO_AF_SPI1);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource5, GPIO_AF_SPI1);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_SPI1);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_SPI1);

//Set chip select high 
GPIOA->BSRRL |= GPIO_Pin_4; // set PE4 high

// enable peripheral clock
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SPI1, ENABLE);

/* configure SPI1 in Mode 0 
 * CPOL = 0 --> clock is low when idle
 * CPHA = 0 --> data is sampled at the first edge
 */
SPI_StructInit(&SPI_InitStruct); // set default config 
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex; // set to full duplex mode, seperate MOSI and MISO lines
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;     // transmit in master mode, NSS pin has to be always high
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_8b; // one packet of data is 8 bits wide
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;        // clock is low when idle
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_1Edge;      // data sampled at first edge
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft ; // set the NSS management to internal and pull internal NSS high
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_4; // SPI frequency is APB2 frequency / 4
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;// data is transmitted MSB first
SPI_Init(SPI1, &SPI_InitStruct); 

SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE); // enable SPI1
}
```

and this is the function that send data

```
 uint8_t SPI1_send(uint8_t data){

SPI1->DR = data; // write data to be transmitted to the SPI data register
while( !(SPI1->SR & SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE) ); // wait until transmit complete
while( !(SPI1->SR & SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) ); // wait until receive complete
while( SPI1->SR & SPI_I2S_FLAG_BSY ); // wait until SPI is not busy anymore
return SPI1->DR; // return received data from SPI data register
}
```

I think that i have set the good configuration (the choice of pins is not wrong in my opinion and also the configuration of the bus used ) the following pictures are extracted from the [STM32F407 DataSheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00037051.pdf)
[image: SPI_Alternate_Function_Mapping]
[image]

The problem is that the data in the DR registry is different than the data passed as argument [image: Debug_Figure].I don't know why this happen .Could anyone guide me to the right point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the SPI section from [this book](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~geobrown/book.pdf) my problem is solved, i just connect SPI MOSI to SPI MISO pin (PA6 and PA7) then used the following function :

```
int spiReadWrite(SPI_TypeDef* SPIx, uint8_t *rbuf,
const uint8_t *tbuf, int cnt, enum spiSpeed speed)
{
int i;
SPIx->CR1 = (SPIx->CR1 & ~SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_256) |
speeds[speed];
for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++){
  if (tbuf) {
  SPI_I2S_SendData(SPIx, *tbuf++);
  } else {
  SPI_I2S_SendData(SPIx, 0xff);
  }
while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPIx, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET);
  if (rbuf) {
  *rbuf++ = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPIx);
  } else {
  SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPIx);
  }
}
return i;
}
```

by using a debugger i can see that the data sent (from tbuf) are succesfully received (in rbuf)

Answer (score 4):

The SPI DR register is not a normal memory location where writing and reading access the same storage.

Instead, writing loads the output shift register, while reading reads the received input.  Depending on device details, reading may also "claim" the input, clearing it from the register until another word is received.

For these reasons, trying to watch the SPI DR with a debugger is not only not going to give you the information you seek, it may even be damaging to the data you would otherwise receive.

Comment: Thx Chris for your reply but i really don't undresatnd why i can't read SPI DR from a debugger and how can i make sure that my data are succesfully written

Comment: You cannot read it, because the hardware does not support reading the "side" of it you write to.  To recover the transmit data you could use a logic analyzer, or perhaps you can disconnect the SPI peripheral (or decline to activate its chip select) and loop the SPI MOSI pin back to the MISO so that the program will ultimately be able to readback the transmit data at the correct time **DO NOT TRY TO USE THE DEBUGGER** as it will read at the wrong time.  Debuggers are not magic - they have very real limitations, and you cannot use one well unless you are willing to learn about and respect those.

Comment: Ultimately there is little purpose to trying to recover the data you just set in the transmit register anyway - if you have real doubts about the code, look at the dissasembly.  If you want to prove you are setting the values you think you are, look at one of the configuration registers instead.  Keep in mind also though, that some special function registers are only valid for a given word width - attempting to read with the wrong width won't necessarily give you part of the data and/or extra nonsense bits, as memory access would, it may fail entirely, as these are not memory locations.

Comment: Thx again for your reply, I desactivated the chip slect and then i loop the SPI MOSI pin back to the MISO pin ,in the instruction return SPI1->DR i should have the right value, however it 's not the case i got hierarchical values(0x08, 0x26...), what is the problem in your opinion am i missing sthing

Answer (score 0):

note that   SCLK_freq = APB2_freq / (BaudRatePrescaler + 1)